# OpenERP - Restrict the product module edit operation for Purchase\User based on status?

Tags: python-2.7, odoo, openerp-7

I inherited the OpenERP Products module and added a new field called stage.
The code is,

```
_columns =  {
    'stage': fields.selection([
        ('pending', 'Pending'),
        ('confirmed', 'Confirmed'),
        ('cancel', 'Cancelled'),
    ], 'Status', select=True, track_visibility='onchange', help='Product Workflow Stages')
```

Now I need a condition that should block the edit operation for `Purchase/User` when the product is in `confirmed` stage.

```
def write(self, cr, uid, ids, datas, context = {} ):
        product_stage = datas['stage']
        if product_stage == 'confirmed':
            return super(purchase_order, self).write(cr, uid, ids, datas, context)
        else:
            raise osv.except_osv('Warning!',"You are not allowed to make changes! '%s'." % product_stage)
```

This condition have to apply only for `Purchase\User`.

I am new to python code. Can anyone help me on this?.

Comment: I found the answer. My code is wrong. Now I know how to code.

Comment: If you found the solution, it would be nice to share the code. Your question has been upvoted 4 times, it might mean that at least four other users are interested in a solution :-)

Answer (score 1):

The following code is working fine for me.

```
def write(self, cr, uid, ids,  datas = {}, context = {} ):
    product_obj=self.pool.get('product.product')
    new_product_obj=product_obj.browse(cr, uid, ids[0], context=context)
    all_groups=self.pool.get('res.groups')
    edit_group = all_groups.browse(cr, uid, all_groups.search(cr,uid,[('name','=','User')])[3])
    groups_users=edit_group.users
    for groups_user in groups_users:
        if uid == groups_user.id:
            if 'confirmed' == new_product_obj.stage:
                raise osv.except_osv('Warning!',"You are not allowed to make any changes in confirmed products!")
            else:
                return super(purchase_order, self).write(cr, uid, ids, datas, context)
    return super(purchase_order, self).write(cr, uid, ids, datas, context)
```